# Add another field to a select query with belongsToMany relationship in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables with M-M relationship. The pivot table however has an additional column.
How can I add this additional column to the query? Is it possible at all? I don;t want to use direct SQL query.

Comment: Stackoverflow it's pretty clear about "showing some work" before asking something. Try harder next time, before ask. It will make you ask more interesting and relevant questions. Hope it helps you the next time you need to ask anything.

Comment: Oh, thank u! Ur comment was constructive! I didn't know it was about how interesting my question was. Will have in mind, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that in the `attach`

```
$user->roles()->attach(1, array('expires' => $expires));
```

Or the `sync`

```
$user->roles()->sync(array(1 => array('expires' => true)));
```

Or the `save`

```
User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, array('expires' => $expires));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid...It is in the documentation:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
```